# Debugging a scheme function that accepts strings

Tags: scheme

I’m working on a Scheme function that takes two words and checks to see if their lengths are the same. It should output 'same length' if they are and specify the longer and shorter string with their lengths if they don't have the same length.
So I tried

```
 (define (strings x y)
      (if (= (string-length x)(string-length y))
          display "same length"
          (string-length x)(string-length y)))
```

but it says that two string-lengths are the same length even if they aren't. It also only prints the string-length of x if I put parentheses on display "same length". I’m not sure how to go about fixing it.

Comment: Scheme doesn't have a procedure called `strings-length`, however it has a procedure called [`string-length`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/r5rs/r5rs-std/r5rs-Z-H-9.html#%25_idx_516). The expression in the second if seems to have extra parantheses. eg. `((something ...))` basically means `something()()` in a C type language and expect the `something()` to return a function that then gets called.

Comment: Yes. There are more misaligments of parentheses. eg. the `not` isn't closed on the same line but  `(display "same length")` is a second argument to it even if `not` only takes one argument. Try reformatting it in an editor that formats Scheme code, like DrRacket's CTRL+i.

Comment: Is there another way I can print out two arguments for a condition where the two strings are not equal?

Comment: Well usually an if has 3 parts.. `(if test-expression then-expression else-expression)`. Your code does the `display` in the `test-expression` and usually you would want it as a part of the `then-expression`.

Comment: I updated my original code and was wondering if you have a different suggestion of how I should go about fixing it?

Answer (score 0):

How you have formatted code does not agree with what an IDE would do. Eg. pasting your code in DrRacket and pressing `CTRL+i` gives me:

```
(define (strings x y)
  (if (not (= (strings-length x)(strings-length y))
           (display "same length")) ; this is second argument to not
      (if (> (strings-length x)(strings-length y))
          ((strings-length x)(strings-length y)))))
```

So the first `if` calls `not` with two arguments because you lack the closing parantesis on the end of the line. You also lack the else clause such that a false test leaves what the result is to the implementation.

Basically you are after this:

```
(if (= (string-length x) (string-length y))
    what-to-do-when-true
    what-to-do-when-false)
```

Notice you don't need the second `if` since you are testing the opposite of the first one and you are guaranteed to end up in the code `what-to-do-when-false`. Also notice I've removed the `not` so you just switch the order. If you'd like you can re-add the `not`, but don't forget the parentheses.

Comment: I applied the changes you suggested and it still only prints out the string-length of x. I need it to print out the string-length of both x and y.

Comment: @Toaster1 yes but now the question is different so the answer need to be updated as well etc. Usually you are expected to add information but not edit completely the question (or you can ask follow-up questions)

Comment: @coredump thank you